# ip conflict vps

Tags: ip

I encountered an error in my website, http://videoof.co.uk.
I have added an A record to all of my DNS servers with the IP address
85.234.141.245,
but it still does not show up.
Can anyone give me some guidance on what should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 5):

Your DNS records are working; I can see that IP when I look up the name.

You probably tried to use that name *before* the DNS entry was created, and your ISP's DNS resolver has cached the non-existence of the record.  Just wait awhile for that cache to expire, and you should see it.

It's normal for DNS changes to not take effect immediately, because of multiple levels of caching throughout the system.

Comment: tanx , I have this problem since last week .usually how many days it take to dns cache expire ?

Comment: @videoof, it shouldn't take more than a day or two.  Are you sure the problem you're having is caused by DNS?  What happens when you try to load that URL?  (I get a "Default Website Page" provided by cPanel.)  If you open a terminal and `ping videoof.co.uk`, does it ping the correct IP?

Comment: i see the same page and when I pinged it also show me right IP i.e. 85.234.141.245 . i dont know what is the problem , it was working fine last week , but now it is not show properly even with server IP i.e. http://85.234.141.245/~videoof/

Comment: @videoof, then your problem isn't DNS, it's the configuration of the server itself.  Make sure your files are actually there, and talk to your hosting provider's technical support staff.